# Branching or ftell() that is Slowing?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

I was viewing the file agents.h on my windows OS,and I wanted to see the c++ code without comments.i striped them out to see the code more clearly with my old program but i was surprised that it took like 2 seconds to finish.the size of the file is 605KB,so it isn't so bad.Why is it that slow.I suspect it is the function ftell() that is doing it,but i can't really tell.Is it branching that is slowing or ftell()?, if ftell(),then what is a better way to throw the FILE pointer back?

**EDIT**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NOT_COMMENT (!DOUBLESLASH_Comment && !ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment)

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    clock_t t1 = clock();

    FILE *input , *output;

    if( fopen_s(&input,argv[1],"r") )
    {
        printf("error opening file %s\n",argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

    if( fopen_s(&output,argv[2],"w") )
    {
        printf("error opening file %s\n",argv[2]);
        return 0;
    }

    char c , d;
                                                                //escape flag
    bool DOUBLESLASH_Comment = 0 , ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment = 0 , flag = 0;

    /* single quotes / double quotes */
    int s_QUOTED = 0 , d_QUOTED = 0;

    while( (c=getc(input)) != EOF )
    {
        switch(c)
        {
        case '\\':
            {
                if( NOT_COMMENT )
                {
                    if( flag == 1 )
                        flag = 0;
                    else
                        flag = 1;
                }
            }break;

        case '\'':
            {
                if( NOT_COMMENT && !d_QUOTED )
                {
                    if( !flag )
                    {
                        s_QUOTED++;
                    }
                }
            }break;

        case '"':
            {
                if( NOT_COMMENT && !flag )
                {
                    if( !s_QUOTED )
                    {
                        d_QUOTED++;
                    }
                }
            }break;

        case '/':
            {
                if( NOT_COMMENT && !d_QUOTED )
                {
                    if( (d=getc(input)) == '*' )
                    {
                        ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment = 1;
                    }
                    else if( d == '/' )
                    {
                        DOUBLESLASH_Comment = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if( d != EOF )
                        {
                            ungetc(d,input);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }break;

        case '*':
            {
                if( ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment )
                {
                    if( (d=getc(input)) == '/')
                    {
                        if( (c=getc(input)) == EOF )
                            return 0;

                        ASTERISK_SLASH_Comment = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if( d != EOF )
                        {
                            ungetc(d,input);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }break;

        case '\n':
            {
                if( DOUBLESLASH_Comment )
                {
                    DOUBLESLASH_Comment = 0;
                }
            }break;
        }

        if( NOT_COMMENT && c != '\\' ) flag = 0;
        if( d_QUOTED == 2 ) d_QUOTED = 0;
        if( s_QUOTED == 2 ) s_QUOTED = 0;

        if( NOT_COMMENT )
        {
            fprintf(output,"%c",c);
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    clock_t t2 = clock();

    double elapsed = (double)(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("time elapsed : %f\n",elapsed);
}
```

Comment: Would this not be significantly easier with a line-based approach instead of parsing one character at a time with a whole load of states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without actually measuring the speed of your code in a profiler (and with the file you use as input, since one I use may have a different set of comments, etc that trigger a different behaviour), it's hard to say for sure. But it looks like you use `fseek( ... )` simply to move back one character. In which case writing your own function for a one character lookahead would be a much better choice.

Something like this:

```
char lookahead = ' ';
bool havelookahead = false;

char getNextChar(FILE *input)
{
    if (havelookahead)
    {
        havelookahead = false;
        return lookahead;
    }
    return getc(input);
}

char peekChar(FILE *input)
{
    if (!havelookahead)
    {
        lookahead = getc(input);
        havelookahead = true;
    }
    return lookahead;
}
```

Then replace your `getc` with `getNextChar` in the beginning of the loop, and where you check the next character with `peekChar` (followed by a dummy `getNextChar()` to consume it).

This is a useful pattern in general for parsing - both at character level and at token level, so it's good learning to understand how this works.

You can also use the standard `ungetc` to "put back" your character that you looked at.

Whether this makes your code run significantly faster or not is hard to say, as I said in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot compile your code, so I cannot make tests. But I suspect that the bottleneck is `fseek` rather than `ftell`. Rejecting a character is a common task in parsing files... and should be implemented by the library or some intermediate layer with some buffering. In this case (rejection of a single character) you can use `ungetc` to achieve that.

So you should replace

```
fseek( file , ( ftell(file) - 1 ) , SEEK_SET );
```

with

```
ungetc('*', file);    // ungetc('/', file); the second time.
```